# gcp bigquery event captured by gcp sink to getting reflected in pubsub subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have the following flow requirement on google-cloud GCP.

1. Any event of table getting created on the particular dataset of bigquery needs to captured in the GCP-SINK
2. For point-1 i have defined the GCP-sink with below inclusion-filter
   `resource.type="bigquery_dataset" AND resource.labels.dataset_id="dataset-name-1" OR resource.labels.dataset_id="finance_dataset"`

3 I can even observe the output generated by the sink if i run the query from "log explorer".
[image: sink_output]

4. The destination for my sink is a pub/sub topic, but for some reason it does not seems to get passed it's subscription.
   Note: There is only one subscription for the above destination pub-sub topic
   [image: pub-sub-description]
5. If is use the inclusion filter as shown below then it works fine but the problem with this approach is that it is capturing event for all of the dataset
   `resource.type="bigquery_resource"`

The events flow actually is quite simple
big-query --> sink --> pub/sub

Comment: I tried your use case and it works fine for me. Can you share the config of your `Topic`, `Subscriber` and `Sink`?

Comment: @ScottB thanks for the response, i did a recheck and  passed this to a new pub/sub topic and i could observe the event in the metrics
Not sure what issue occurred with the old subscription, even though i purged all of it's queue, i try will deleting the old subscription and recreate it to see if it works.